# Get value of ControlType.Spinner element using UIAutomation

Tags: c#, spinner, microsoft-ui-automation

I obtained window and the spinner object:

```
var OrderWindow = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "*NAME*"));

var numberOfXX = OrderWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, "*NAME*"));
```

then I am accessing spinner RangeValuePatterm:

```
RangeValuePattern value = numberOfXX.GetCurrentPattern(RangeValuePattern.Pattern) as RangeValuePattern;
```

And i should be able to use simple:

```
value.SetValue(5);
```

To modify its value, but it is not working. I am getting an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' - Value is greater than Maximum. (What is true, but I don't know how to change maximum allowed value...).

Also I have no idea how to get its current value, since simple:

```
value.Current.Value
```

always return 0, regardless what value is entered. I can simply send keys to set value of a spinner instead accessing it via UIAutomation, but I don't know hot to read out the actual value of the spinner → thus can't check it if it is correct.

Comment: UI Automation automates the way a user would use an app.  Since a user cannot possibly change the maximum value of a spinner, your app cannot either.  If you could then that would end badly when the app gets a value that it does not expect.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so, but it was worth to play with it.

Comment: i need the value of spinner is their any solution it also not show the edit control in it